# Windows form in smart device project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, smart-device

I have develop a small project for my Handheld device(Windows CE 7.0) using VS 2008 pro.  I has a windows form with 2 text box in the project.  I build the cab file and install the apps into the handheld device but the UI seem like weird.  It has extra gray color area appear on top of the UI but not sure what is the gray area is.  I attached the screen shot of the UI.  Please help, how I can remove those area,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think the color is the color of a panel docked on top remove the panel

Comment: Hi Cyril, I didn't put any panel during design the UI.